# Postgresql - Query to multiply time by number

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I'm creating a query to multiply a time by a number.

The time is the result of a query of the annual working hours of a person. The purpose is calculate the 25% then I want to multiply the time by 0.25

Example:

```
Time1: 100:00:00
```

[format H:M:s]

For this I've tried this query:

```
SELECT '100:00:00'::time * 0.25
```

PostgreSQL returns:

```
ERROR: the time / date value is out of range: «100: 00: 00»
LINE 2: SELECT '100: 00: 00' :: time * 0.25
```

The error is clear. My conversion of the time is out of range because the time object only is valid to 24 hours. In this case is working fine:

```
SELECT '24:00:00'::time * 0.25
```

Result:

```
"06:00:00"
```

Someone have any idea?

Comment: A `time` value contains the time of the day. And on planet earth the highest "time of the day" is `24:00:00` because after that the next day begins (did you ever see a clock that displayed `100:00:00`) . It seems you are actually looking for a way to represent a duration, not a "time of the day". Durations are represented with an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) data type in SQL

Comment: Yes the time is a day, I agree. The durations are interval value, ok! Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Time values are limited to 24 hours.  You can do the calculation using other units.  For instance, the following translates this to seconds:

```
select 0.25 * ( (string_to_array('100:00:00', ':'))[1]::int*60*60 +
                (string_to_array('100:00:00', ':'))[2]::int*60 +
                (string_to_array('100:00:00', ':'))[3]::int
              ) as num_seconds
```

Note that you also cannot represent the result as a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INTERVAL`, as in:

```
select interval '100 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds' * 0.25
```

or:

```
select interval '100:00:00' * 0.25
```

or:

```
select '100:00:00'::interval * 0.25
```

The result (for all of them):

```
 ?column?
 --------
 25:00:00
```